# MySQL Server 5.5 : unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, ubuntu

when updating MySQL Server on Ubuntu, installer asks me if I want to update my root password. Whether I do change it or not, I get the following error :

> unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user

dpkg error :

> Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ... 150803
>   22:14:05 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of
>   key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
>   Please use the full name instead. 150803 22:14:05 [Note]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process
>   4824 ... start: Job failed to start invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql,
>   action "start" failed. dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5
>   (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned
>   error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
>   mysql-server:  mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
>   Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):  dependency
>   problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while
>   processing:  mysql-server-5.5  mysql-server E: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.13.0-61-generic (buildd@lgw01-50) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 29 11:21:34 UTC 2015
```

I've tried everything we can see on the Internet : purging mysql-server, deleting /var/lib/mysql, ... but still I get this error.

Has anyone succeeded in updating mysql (or an alternative database compatible with Wordpress)?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly caused by an unsuccessful manual installation of Mysql server .
Request  you to purge  and reinstall again. Can follow the  hacks provided  here

https://askubuntu.com/questions/253023/unable-to-set-password-for-the-mysql-root-user